# Raspeberry pi b+ wifi connection

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I've got Raspberry pi B+. I've loaded raspberry wheezy image into MMC card.

- I've got wifi router.I want to connect Pi B+ board with wifi router without using wifi USB adapter.
- Is it possible?If yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to connect Pi B+ board with wifi router without using wifi USB adapter.

- Wifi routers usually have a few ethernet ports, so you could plug it into the router.
- If you have another computer that has wifi and an ethernet port, you could connect it to that.  If the other computer is running linux, there's [basic instructions here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing) (in the Arch wiki, but this is the same for any distro; note that it is not made clear there that in the iptables rules `net0` should in this case be the name of the ethernet interface and `internet0` the name of the wifi interface).

If you meant, is there a magical way for the pi to communicate via wifi without a wifi adapter, the answer is no.